# Filtering a Collection in C#

Tags: c#, linq, syndication-feed

I'm currently using SyndicationFeed to extract an image from a syndication item.

Each item has a collection of links. For each link collection I want to do the following:

1. check the first instance where `link.MediaType` contains an image,
2. if it does, return `link.Uri` else return an empty string

I wanted to do something like this:

```
var imageLink = image.Links.First(where( s.mediaType contains "image" && s.mediaType != null))
if (imageLink){
  string imageUrl = imageLink.Uri
}
```

Currently I have a lot of if statements. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you want:

```
using System.Linq;

string GetUri(SyndicationFeed image)
{
    return image.Links.Where(link => link != null && link.Contains("image")).FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
}
```

Comment: You could make this better by removing the `Where` call and putting the condition on the `FirstOrDefault` call

Comment: quick question, so I have a field called mediaTypes in image.Links, and I need to check the specific field mediaTypes to see if it contains "image", does link.Contains do that?

Comment: @lost9123193 That would depend on what you mean by 'to see if it contains "image"' exactly.

Comment: 'Contains' checks for 'image' as a substring, if you need case insensitivity you want to use something like string.Compare or something link.Equals. I did the shortest idiomatic way based on your request.

You could also put the expression in FirstOrDefault also like Camilo mentioned. It makes the line a tad shorter. I just find when I write code like this I tend to have  ALOT of these and sometimes you need to chain Where, Select, Groupby's so like them all using the same format so am normally explicit.